# What's the cleanest way to open directories using FZF instead of netrw?

Tags: netrw, fzf

I have a dirty implementation of using FZF instead of netrw to open directories:

```
" netrw
let g:loaded_netrw       = 1
let g:loaded_netrwPlugin = 1

" Directories
function! MaybeOpenFzfForDir()
  if getftype(bufname()) == 'dir'
    let g:dir_bufnr = bufnr()
    call fzf#vim#files(bufname())
    execute 'bd' . g:dir_bufnr
    unlet g:dir_bufnr 
 "   execute 'wincmd w'
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter * call MaybeOpenFzfForDir()
```

The goal is to support: a) commandline invocation of vim to load a directory, and b) loading a directory in an existing vim session via `:edit`.

However, the code suffers from the following problems:

1. Vim still prints the `is a directory` error when entering.
2. Once you select the file from FZF, it complains about deleting the last buffer. (For commandline invocation case).
3. If you don't delete the empty directory buffer, 2 instances of FZF come up simultaneously.

What I want is for it to be clean just like netrw, nerdtree, dirvish, etc. I've tried to read their vimscript but I get lost in their twisty paths. What can I tweak to clean this up?